# Total length of list in using struts 2 tag

Tags: java, struts2

I iterate a list using Struts 2 tags.

```
<s:iterator value="popUpScreenDetailsList" status ="rowCounter">
    //do something
<s:/iterator>
```

Is there a way, by which I can get the length of the list without iterating?

The motivation to do it, is to use javascript to validate checkboxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a Java List object, then you can also get the length (size) by

`<s:property value="%{getPopUpScreenDetailsList().size()}"/>`

Answer (score 3):

```
<s:property value="popUpScreenDetailsList.size"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Java List object, then you can also get the length (size) by

not getPopUpScreenDetailsList().size()